# How can I do so that my middleware can reload the page in the routes using React?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, nest

How can I do so that my middleware can reload the page in the routes using React since the middleware does not work, the page remains blank if the token is not there and I access the route and I want it to redirect me to the login

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenValidationMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  async use(req: Request, res?: Response, next?: NextFunction) {
    // 1. We should Verify the presence of the token and validate its contents
    const currentToken = req.cookies[config.auth.authTokenCookieName]
      ? req.cookies[config.auth.authTokenCookieName]
      : null;
    // 2. If token does not exist, or is invalid, or has expired beyond a given threshold, we redirect to login
    if (!currentToken) {
      res.clearCookie(config.auth.authTokenCookieName, null);
      res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else {
      // 3. If token is expired but not too long ago, we ask for a renewed token
      const { expireTime, sessionId, username } = decryptToken(currentToken);
      const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
      // 4. If the life span of the token has been reached, we should proceed to analyze the last action of the user
      if (expireTime < currentTime) {
        // 5. Call GET /session by sessionId for obtaining the lastAction Time
        const sessionData = await findOne(sessionId);
        if (sessionData && sessionData.lastActionTime) {
          const lastActionTime = sessionData.lastActionTime;
          // TODO
          const tokenRenewalMaxDuration: number =
            +config.auth.tokenRenewalMaxDuration;
          if (currentTime - lastActionTime <= tokenRenewalMaxDuration * 1000) {
            // We need to renovate the token
            // 6. Update the Cookie with the new Token
            const { token, tokenExpireTime } = generateAuthToken(
              decryptToken(currentToken),
            );
            res.cookie(
              config.auth.authTokenCookieName,
              token,
              getCookieOptions(),
            );
            console.log(
              'TokenValidationMiddleware.use() - [' +
              username +
              '] - Token Renewed.',
            );
            // 7. Call PATCH /session by sessionId with new Token Expire Time
            const newExpireTime: number = +tokenExpireTime;
            try {
              updateExpireTime(sessionId, newExpireTime, token);
              next();
            } catch (error) {
              console.log('TokenValidationMiddleware.use() - [' + username + '] - Failed to update Session Expire Time: ' + error.message);
              res.clearCookie(config.auth.authTokenCookieName, getCookieOptions());
              res.redirect('/login?error=' + error.message);
            }
          }
          else {
            // We need to redirect to login, as token has not been used recently
            console.log('TokenValidationMiddleware.use() - [' + username + '] - User Token has Expired. Taking user to login.');
            res.clearCookie(config.auth.authTokenCookieName, getCookieOptions());
            res.redirect('/login');
          }
        }
      } else {
        next();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can try throws error 405 for example in res.redirect(405. "/login:") so that react can read that exception in a queryClient that inside has a QueryCache with an onError() function but the error does not arrive

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

React is a client-side library with no built-in middleware functionality like server-side frameworks such as Express. It provides a way to declare routes in the application and renders components based on the current URL path.

Comment: This seems more of a comment, rather than an actual answer. If this does answer the question in your opinion, please read [answer] and [edit] the post for clarity.